# Error is not showing after scanning a item thats not on the firestore database

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I did this personal project of mine where a barcode scanner would scan for data inside firestore database. I have this problem when I scanned a barcode thats not on the database it wont show the error message is just shows a empty scan item container which I made. Let me know if someone can figure why. I tried everything still couldnt fix it.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("products")
                .where("barcode", isEqualTo: '$barcodeScanRes')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Dialog(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 300,
                    child: Text('Product Not Found'),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Dialog(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 350,
                    child: Column(children: [
                      Container(
                          height: 350,
                          width: 165,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              DocumentSnapshot products =
                              snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                              return ScanCard(products: products);
                            },
                          )),
                    ]),
                  ),
                );
```

#Scan Card

```
 class ScanCard extends StatelessWidget {
 const ScanCard({
 Key? key,
 required this.products,
 }) : super(key: key);
 final DocumentSnapshot products;


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
String _userId = user!.uid;


return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      height: 180,
      width: 160,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
      child: Image.network(products['img']),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0 / 4),
      child: Text(
        products['name'],
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          fontSize: 18,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          "Size: " + products['size'],
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14, color: Colors.brown),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 30,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      children: [
        Text(
          "\tRs. " + products['price'],
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 40,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.add_shopping_cart,
          color: Colors.black,
          size: 25,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    SizedBox(
      width: 10,
    ),
    SizedBox(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: RaisedButton(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text(
            "Add to cart",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('userData')
                .doc(_userId)
                .collection('cartData')
                .doc();
            documentReference.set({
              'uid': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
              'barcode': products['barcode'],
              'img': products['img'],
              'name': products['name'],
              'size': products['size'],
              'price': products['price'],
              'id': documentReference.id
            }).then((result) {
              addToCartMessage(context).then((value) => {
                Navigator.pop(context)
              });
            }).catchError((e) {
              print(e);
            });
           },
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you are showing `Product not found` based on the condition:- `!snapshot.hasData` but this conditon means that data is being fetched so at this time rather show a progress indicator.

And to handle when data is not present in backend then add another condition:- `if(snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty)` and here show your dialogbox of Product not found...

Final Code Snippet will look  like:-

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) 
     return Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator));//or return a black container if you don't want to show anything while fetching data from firestore
else if (snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty) {
                return Dialog(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 300,
                    child: Text('Product Not Found'),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Dialog(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 350,
                    child: Column(children: [
                      Container(
                          height: 350,
                          width: 165,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              DocumentSnapshot products =
                              snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                              return ScanCard(products: products);
                            },
                          )),
                    ]),
                  ),
                );
               }
```

Comment: Thank you works like a charm! This fixed a lot of issues I have been facing